# Loss of precision float in python

Tags: python

I have a list called scores of varying -log probabilities.

when I call this function:

```
maxState = scores.pop(scores.index(max(scores)))
```

and print `maxState`, I realize that the `maxState` loses its precision as a float. Is there a way I can get the maxState without losing precision?

ex: I print out the list scores: `[-35.7971525669589, -34.67875545008369]`
and print maxState, I get this: `-34.6787554501`
(You can see it's rounded)

Comment: @Flav: Put the floating point value in a container, and it is trivial to reproduce.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to actually use "print"

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing string presentation with actual contents. Nowhere is precision lost, only the string produced to write to your console is using a rounded value rather than show you all digits. And always remember that float numbers are digital approximations, not precise values.

Python floats are formatted differently when using the `str()` and `repr()` functions; in a list or other container, `repr()` is used, but print it directly and `str()` is used.

If you don't like either option, format it explicitly with the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) and specifying a precision:

```
print format(maxState, '.12f')
```

to print it with 8 decimals, for example.

Demo:

```
>>> maxState = -34.67875545008369
>>> repr(maxState)
'-34.67875545008369'
>>> str(maxState)
'-34.6787554501'
>>> format(maxState, '.8f')
'-34.67875545'
>>> format(maxState, '.12f')
'-34.678755450084'
```

The `repr()` output is *roughly* equivalent to using `'.17g'` as the format, while `str()` is equivalent to `'.12g'`; here the precision denotes when to use scientific notation (`e`) and when to display in floating point notation (`f`).

I say *roughly* because the `repr()` output aims to give you round-trippable output; see the [change notes for Python 3.1 on `float()` representation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes), which where backported to Python 2.7:

> What is new is how the number gets displayed. Formerly, Python used a simple approach. The value of `repr(1.1)` was computed as `format(1.1, '.17g')` which evaluated to `'1.1000000000000001'`. The advantage of using 17 digits was that it relied on IEEE-754 guarantees to assure that `eval(repr(1.1))` would round-trip exactly to its original value. The disadvantage is that many people found the output to be confusing (mistaking intrinsic limitations of binary floating point representation as being a problem with Python itself).
>
> The new algorithm for `repr(1.1)` is smarter and returns `'1.1'`. Effectively, it searches all equivalent string representations (ones that get stored with the same underlying float value) and returns the shortest representation.

Comment: minor note to your `floating point notation (f)`. In the docs it is defined as a fixed point: `Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6`. See: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language