# seeing the true value of a float in a python program

Tags: python, floating-point, python-2.x

The python cmd line shows the true value of a float readily

```
>>> 1.5-1.4
0.10000000000000009
```

The obvious way to see it from within a python program is to print it

```
>>> print 1.5-1.4
0.1
```

which seems to automatically round it? Is there a way to see the true value of a float from within a program?

Comment: `0.10000000000000009` isn't the true value either - it's rounded too. If you want to see the *true* value, use [`decimal.Decimal(whatever_float)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Also, if you can, migrate to Python 3 already. Python 2 is under a year from end of life.

Comment: "True" value is complicated here. The string produced by `repr` (for example, in the Python REPL here) is rounded differently than the string produced by `str` (as used by `print`). But neither one is more correct than the other: if you parse both those strings back into `float` objects you will see that they both represent the same value (which is not exactly 0.1, but rather *the representable value closest to 0.1*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loss of precision float in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26441781/loss-of-precision-float-in-python)

Comment: @DanielPryden: It's not actually the closest representable value to 0.1. It's 6 steps above the closest representable value.

Comment: @user2357112: Good catch (I was just eyeballing it). The closest float to 0.1 is `0x1.999999999999ap-4` and the result of 1.5 - 1.4 is `0x1.99999999999a0p-4`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that IEEE 754 double precision can require up to 767 significand digits to print true value in base 10 (not accounting leading zeros), but only 53 bits, maybe true value in base 10 is not what you want.

`repr` is good enough: it is shortest base 10 number rounding back to same float.
Thus, every two different float have a different `repr`, and it will identify your float uniquely.

If it's for having good view of internal representation, you can print in base 16 with `hex`, you'll get a leading 1 (or 0 for subnormals) and 13 hexadecimal "digits" encoding 4 bits each, plus base 2 exponent (written in base 10).

Here is an example:

```
import decimal
f=1<<1022
u=1<<(1022+53-1)
y=2/f-1/u
print(repr(y))
print(decimal.Decimal(y))
print(len(str(decimal.Decimal(y))))
print(float.hex(y))
```

Output is

```
4.4501477170144023e-308                                                                                                 
4.4501477170144022721148195934182639518696390927032912960468522194496444440421538910330590478162701758282983178260792422
137401728773891892910553144148156412434867599762821265346585071045737627442980259622449029037796981144446145705102663115
100318287949527959668236039986479250965780342141637013812613333119898765515451440315261253813266652951306000184917766328
660755595837392240989947807556594098101021612198814605258742579179000071675999344145086087205681577915435923018910334964
869420614052182892431445797605163650903606514140377217442262561590244668525767372446430075513332450079650686719491377688
478005309963967709758965844137894433796621993967316936280457084866613206797017728916080020698679408551343728867675409720
757232455434770912461317493580281734466552734375E-308                                                                   
773                                                                                                                     
0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022
```

You can hardly decipher the second form with its 773 characters (767 significand digits+1char for dot+5chars for exponent).

**NOTA:** in python 2.7, set y with this line

```
y=float(2/decimal.Decimal(f)-1/decimal.Decimal(u))
```

Comment: Beside, I did all the computations in Squeak Smalltalk where there are only strict IEEE 754 double precision and no other possible Float representation, and where all the binary/decimal conversion can be performed without effort thanks to unbounded LargeInteger and Fraction... I'm fairly confident that I can do mistakes, that's why I prefer to use robust tools and double check... Isn't 0x1.fffffffffffffp-1022 representable, and how many significand digits do you count for its exact base-10 value?

Answer (score 1):

In some Python implementations, you can use `print("%.9999g" % (1.5-1.4))`. This should print the number with 9999 significant digits but with trailing zeroes suppressed—in effect all the significant digits of the number.

Python implementations may rely on underlying hardware and software for floating-point services, possibly including the formatting provided by `%.9999g`. Some implementations might not provide all digits needed to see the exact value. They may show the value rounded to about 16 digits, for example, in spite of the fact 9999 were requested.

In Python 2.7.10 on macOS 10.14.2, the above prints “0.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625”, which is the exact value.

(In comparison, `print("%.9999g" % .1)` prints “0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625”.)